# Time derivative of contact jacobian

Tags: drake

I was implementing some ideas from
[[1]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7803255) and
[[2]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7487270), and I came across the need to calculate Jc_dot. For example in [1] they project the linearized system into the nullspace of the contact constraints (top right of the second page). From what I understand, the approach in [2] is similar, but extended to the time-varying case.

From reading another stackoverflow question on this topic, [[Derivative of jacobian in drake]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65675339/derivative-of-jacobian-in-drake/65675828#65675828), it appears that drake does not have a way to directly calculate this matrix.

I was wondering what the best approach is to calculate Jc_dot? The way I currently obtain Jc_dot is by iteratively setting one of the velocity elements to 1 and calling the CalcBiasSpatialAcceleration function in drake. However, when I check the rank of Jc and Jc_dot, they are different and I cannot find a reason why that should be the case. So, I suspect there might be some issue with my method.

Here is the implementation for reference:

```
def makeJc_dot(plant, context, points, p_BoBP_B = np.zeros(3)):

    frame_world = plant.world_frame()
    v = np.zeros(num_vel)
    Jc_dot = np.zeros((6*len(points), num_vel))

    for index, point in enumerate(points):
        
        frame_B = plant.GetFrameByName(point)

        for col in range(num_vel):
            v[col] = 1.
            plant.SetVelocities(context, v)
            
            Sp_acc = plant.CalcBiasSpatialAcceleration(context,
                            JacobianWrtVariable.kV,
                            frame_B,
                            p_BoBP_B,
                            frame_world,
                            frame_world)

            Jc_dot[0 + 6*index:3 + 6*index, col] = Sp_acc.rotational()
            Jc_dot[3 + 6*index:6 + 6*index, col] = Sp_acc.translational()

            v[col] = 0

    return Jc_dot
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that you cannot get the desired result with the method you've proposed.  The term `Jdot*v` does not only depend on velocities in the `v` term that is visible here.  `Jdot` itself also depends on velocities, because
`\dot{J} = \sum_i dJdqi(q) \dot{qi}`.

One approach that should work well and be relatively clean is to use autodiff on `CalcJacobianSpatialVelocity` to get `dJdqi`, then compute that sum yourself. Or if your autodiff powers are strong enough, then you could even initialize the autodiff `q` variables to contain `dqdt` in their derivatives; so you can avoid the loop.

[This should be a reasonable tutorial](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Drake-0b3b2c53-a7ad-441b-80f8-bf8350752305/project/Tutorials-2b4fc509-aef2-417d-a40d-6071dfed9199/%2Fmultibody_plant_autodiff_mass.ipynb) for that autodiff workflow.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, the first approach should be sufficient for my use case